# Issues compiling thrift tutorial with GHC 7.6.3

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, thrift

I tried compiling the file HaskellServer.hs from thrift-0.9.0/tutorial/hs with ghc 7.6.3 to
no avail.

On the commandline I called

> thrift --gen hs tutorial.thrift
>
> thrift --gen hs shared.thrift

which worked without any errors.

After that, I tried to compile with

> ghc HaskellServer.hs

but I get the following error output:

```
[1 of 7] Compiling Shared_Types     ( Shared_Types.hs, Shared_Types.o ) [flags changed]
[2 of 7] Compiling SharedService_Iface ( SharedService_Iface.hs, SharedService_Iface.o ) [flags
changed]
[3 of 7] Compiling SharedService    ( SharedService.hs, SharedService.o ) [flags changed]
[4 of 7] Compiling Tutorial_Types   ( Tutorial_Types.hs, Tutorial_Types.o ) [flags changed]
[5 of 7] Compiling Calculator_Iface ( Calculator_Iface.hs, Calculator_Iface.o ) [flags changed]
[6 of 7] Compiling Calculator       ( Calculator.hs, Calculator.o ) [flags changed]
[7 of 7] Compiling Main             ( HaskellServer.hs, HaskellServer.o )

HaskellServer.hs:48:33:
    Couldn't match type `GHC.Int.Int32' with `Int'
    Expected type: Maybe Int
      Actual type: Maybe GHC.Int.Int32
    In the first argument of `fromJust', namely `k'
    In the second argument of `(!)', namely `(fromJust k)'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `(myLog ! (fromJust k))'

HaskellServer.hs:73:60:
    Couldn't match type `Int' with `GHC.Int.Int32'
    Expected type: Maybe GHC.Int.Int32
      Actual type: Maybe Int
    In the `f_InvalidOperation_what' field of a record
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `InvalidOperation
         {f_InvalidOperation_what = Just $ fromEnum $ op work,
          f_InvalidOperation_why = Just "Cannot divide by 0"}'
    In the expression:
      throw
      $ InvalidOperation
          {f_InvalidOperation_what = Just $ fromEnum $ op work,
           f_InvalidOperation_why = Just "Cannot divide by 0"}

HaskellServer.hs:74:64:
    Couldn't match expected type `Data.Text.Lazy.Internal.Text'
                with actual type `[Char]'
    In the first argument of `Just', namely `"Cannot divide by 0"'
    In the `f_InvalidOperation_why' field of a record
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `InvalidOperation
         {f_InvalidOperation_what = Just $ fromEnum $ op work,
          f_InvalidOperation_why = Just "Cannot divide by 0"}'

HaskellServer.hs:79:53:
    Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Data.Text.Lazy.Internal.Text'
    Expected type: Data.Text.Lazy.Internal.Text
      Actual type: String
    In the return type of a call of `show'
    In the first argument of `Just', namely `(show val)'
    In the second argument of `SharedStruct', namely
      `(Just (show val))'

HaskellServer.hs:80:52:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `GHC.Int.Int32'
    In the first argument of `M.insert', namely `logid'
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `(M.insert logid logEntry)'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `return . (M.insert logid logEntry)'
```

Obviously, something's wrong with the types but I can't say if it's a problem with my specific
GHC version or with thrift itself.

Here is the code for the first error message (HaskellServer.hs:48:33):

```
instance SharedService_Iface CalculatorHandler where
  getStruct self k = do
    myLog <- readMVar (mathLog self)
    return $ (myLog ! (fromJust k))
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

---

**Update**

The generated thrift files list the compile flags used:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-name-shadowing #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-unused-imports #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-unused-matches #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-missing-fields #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-missing-signatures #-}
```

Comment: It looks suspicious that GHC recompiles all the modules because `[flags changed]`. It would be interesting to know what flags were passed by `thrift` that are now missing.

Comment: @DanielFischer I've updated my question with the compile flags I've found. What do you think?

Comment: Hmm, `-fno-warn-xyz` should not be considered a flag change that requires recompilation. Can `thrift --gen hs shared.thrift` be run in a verbose mode that spits out the GHC invocation?

Comment: Well, I tried `thrift -debug -v --gen hs shared.thrift` but the output is kinda useless. It just prints the parse output and finally says `Generating "hs"` before returning to the prompt. No reference to ghc anywhere.

Comment: Yuck. I'm not going to install thrift (whatever that is) just to debug this issue, so I'm afraid I can't help you with this, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what types you actually use without seeing more of your code, but I have a hunch here that thrift generates things that expect `GHC.Int.Int32` while your code expects `Int`

Comment: That might be it. All code is from the official tutorial which comes with the thrift package. Maybe the Haskell tutorial is outdated?